# Realistic 3d rotation animation of UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, core-animation

I'm trying to find a way to animate 3D rotating of UIView. I want it looks like animation of push notification if you select "Banner" style. I'm trying to use something like

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
CATransform3D t = CATransform3DIdentity;
t = CATransform3DTranslate(t, 0, -self.bounds.size.height/2, 0);
t = CATransform3DRotate(t, M_PI_2, 1, 0, 0);
t = CATransform3DTranslate(t, 0, -self.bounds.size.height/2, 0);
[anim setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity]];
[anim setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:t]];
anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[anim setDuration:0.25];
anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
anim.delegate = self;
[self.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"Rotation"];
```

But this looks flat and not so realistic 3D as an banners of push notifications. How can I make this animation more realistic?

Comment: The main part of the realism is that you are missing perspective. Set `t.m34 = -1.0/500.0;` before you start transforming it (you can read why in the end of [this long post](http://ronnqvi.st/the-math-behind-transforms/)).  Other than that, animating translate-rotate-translate is going to do it on a straight line (you can see what I'm talking about [here](http://ronnqvi.st/translate-rotate-translate/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a deep look at how [CMNavBarNotificationView](https://github.com/edgurgel/CMNavBarNotificationView) is implemented.

Plus, there are different types of CALayer, and you might want to pick a desired one from `+(Class)layerClass` of your animated view. It seems me that you're sticking with plain CALayer.